# Replace specific value with a string inside a tag on a foreach loop

Tags: php, html, replace, foreach

I'm trying to replace a query field-specific value with a string. Actually my code shows the string at a side of the value.

Code:

```
foreach ($fieldquery as $key) {
    $color = ( $key['Oportunidad_Minutos'] >= 60 ) ? 'text-danger' : 'text-success';
    $message = ( $key['Oportunidad_Minutos'] >= 10000 ) ? 'A la espera de Triage' : '';
    $table .= '<tr>'
 . '<td scope="row"><span  class="'.$color.'">'. $key['Oportunidad_Minutos']. $message . '</span></td>'
    . '</tr>';
}
$table .=  '</table>';
$table .= "<script>var i = 0; setTimeout(()=>{location.reload();},100000);</script>"; 

print($table);
```

I need to replace the value if is equal or greater than 100000 or make the value not visible...
Any suggests?
Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Don't display `$key['Oportunidad_Minutos']` directly, put it into the variable.

```
foreach ($fieldquery as $key) {
    $color = ( $key['Oportunidad_Minutos'] >= 60 ) ? 'text-danger' : 'text-success';
    $message = ( $key['Oportunidad_Minutos'] >= 10000 ) ? 'A la espera de Triage' : $key['Oportunidad_Minutos'];
    $table .= '<tr>'
 . '<td scope="row"><span  class="'.$color.'">'. $message . '</span></td>'
    . '</tr>';
}
```